# How can this iteration done in java?

Tags: java, arraylist, iteration

I have a bean say "orderHistory" it has a list "order" and order has "orderitem" list. In orderitem list i have 2 props "orederitemno","orderitemname".. Now my iteration is to get "orederitemno","orderitemname" in seperate "orederitemnolist","orderitemnamelist"...

OrderHistory->Order->OrderItem->"orederitemno","orderitemname" then put them in seperate lists... Any suggestion how this can be done...

Comment: If this is homework, pleas tag it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply iterate over each list and store the two properties in two different lists:

```
List<String> itemNos = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> itemNames = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Order order : orderHistory.getOrders()) {
  for (OrderItem item : order.getItems()) {
    itemNos.add(item.getItemNo());
    itemNames.add(item.getItemName());
  }
}
```